# Puppet - Bundler does not install a gem from GitHub

Tags: github, rubygems, bundler, vagrant, puppet

I have a virtual machine where I want to run Rails application. I use Vagrant to run it and Puppet as the provision tool.

I want to run `bundle install` during the provision so the VM is ready. I use this:

```
exec { 'bundle install':
  command => 'bundle install',
  cwd => '/vagrant/',
  logoutput => true,
}
```

All gems but one are installed. The problem is with `ember-rails`, which is the only one with a GitHub repo specified in Gemfile:

```
gem 'ember-rails', github: 'emberjs/ember-rails'
```

I think this must be a Puppet issue. When I ssh into the VM and run `bundle install` manually, the gem is downloaded and used. When running provision via Vagrant, Puppet logs this message, but the gem seems to be missing:

```
/Stage[main]/Bundler/Exec[bundle install]/returns: Using ember-rails (0.9.2) from git://github.com/emberjs/ember-rails.git (at master)
```

I have noticed one difference. When I run `bundle install` manually, Bundler logs this:

```
Fetching git://github.com/emberjs/ember-rails.git
```

However, there is no such message in the Puppet log. Any ideas what might be the problem?

Comment: Try to specify a `path` (http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#exec-attribute-path) attribute. May be without it bundle can't find a `git` command and fails silently.

Comment: I have specified path. Without it, bundle failed with error messages. So that's not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Gems installed from git repos are only visible to Bundler and do not appear in `gem list`. This is normal and does not indicate a problem. Is there a problem actually running your app?